# Time derivative of relative entropy in this setting

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I was reading the following article : https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.13097.pdf and a question came up.

In page 30 in the proof of Lemma 16, when taking the time derivative of the KL divergence, there is an exchange of the time derivative and the integral.

How do we know that this can be done? I expect that some sort of integrability conditions are proved in an analogous way as in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.11331.pdf Lemma 14 under stronger assumptions.

What are the specific steps in this relaxed setting? Would this work in an even more general setting i.e replacing Assumption 3 with Local Lipschitzness?

Thank you in advance.